# hibernate where clause with projection

Tags: hibernate, criteria, where-clause

There's a table name STUDENTS with column    studentName and studentID

I want to run a query like

```
SELECT studentName 
FROM STUDENTS 
WHERE studentId ='1';
```

in hibernate criteria and want to save this result in some String variable

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like:

```
String result = (String)sess.createCriteria(Students.class)
    .add(Restrictions.eq("studentId",1))
    .setProjection(Property.forName('studentName'))
    .uniqueResult();
```

Comment: Thanks :) ,it works      ,now this result is actually some date ,next i want to compare this date with some other date ,just check which date is greater   like 2011-05-25 00:35:07  or 2011-07-25 00:35:08    in my previous SQL i was using   (UNIX_TIMESTAMP(r.lastupdatedate) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP (e.lastlogindate))>=1 "      , you have any idea what will i use nowi.e in hibernate criteria to compare two dates.   thanks

Comment: You can compare this date using the Restrictions api.  Something like:  Restrictions.gt(yourDate, resultFromAboveDate).  If you want to use the query above as a sub query in a larger query that compares dates then I recommend reading the hibernate documentation on detached queries with the Criteria api: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html

Comment: createCriteria is deprecated.